# Parametrized value of Apache Tomcat Context Attributes or Context variables?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, context.xml

I have java webapp under Tomcat with such sample context:

```
<Context path="reports" docBase="E:\generatedReports"></Context>
```

On unix attribute docBase different:

```
<Context path="reports" docBase="/usr/generatedReports"></Context>
```

Can I have ONE context.xml (for crossplatform and keeping simple build scripts)?
Value of docBase attribute must be parameter managed in other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically Yes, you can keep one file and parametrize it when building.

The problem with doing this via build scripts is that `context.xml` sits outside the `webapps` and is part of the `conf`, i.e. the Tomcat installation directory.

You ideally want minimum interference with files in the `conf` folder and so rather than having it as part of the build and released artifacts, I would suggest you version control it as `context.xml.windows` and `context.xml.unix` or something similar.

And yourself or your admin should manually change/edit these files ensuring all changes are justified.